# How to add a Splash Screen in KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Whenever I open my application (on android) made using KivyMD, it show it's own splash screen. How to remove it or add our own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `buildozer.spec` file there will be an option for `Presplash of the application`. I guess it will be commented so just uncomment it and enter the path of your splash image.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [screen manager module](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) to have multiple screens. Then use [clock module](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) to change the screen using a timer. If you want some animations in the splash screen you can use GIF image or [Animation module](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.animation.html).

Comment: I do not want to add an extra splash screen over the default. I think it need some modification while compiling it to an APK